# A specific decomposition of square matrices over arbitrary ring

Tags: matrices, ring-theory

Let $R$ be any ring with identity $1$. If we take $$A=\begin{bmatrix}a_{11}&a_{12}\\a_{21}&a_{22}\end{bmatrix},E=\begin{bmatrix}a_{11}-1&2-a_{11}\\a_{11}-1&2-a_{11}\end{bmatrix}$$
in $M_2(R)$, then

1. $E^2=E$ and
2. For $$A-E=\begin{bmatrix}1&a_{12}+a_{11}-2\\a_{21}-a_{11}+1&a_{22}+a_{11}-2\end{bmatrix},$$ there exist two invertible matrices $P,Q\in M_2(R)$ such that $$P(A-E)Q=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&c\end{bmatrix}$$ for an appropriate $c$. **I am stuck in understanding part $2$.** Please suggest me how to prove part 2. This proof is given in a well known research article.

Comment: What is the title of this well known research article?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think of $P$ as doing row operations and $Q$ as doing column operations. You can use the $1$ in $(A-E)_{11}$ to put $0$ outside the diagonal.

Something like $$P = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 1 - a_{21} + a_{11} & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$ and similar for $Q$.

Comment: Thank You so much. Now it is clear to me.